# Lost connection to device: Why doesn't my Flutter project connect to the android emulator?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

I cannot solve this error. The app seems to build just fine but, for some reason, can't seem to connect to the emulator. It always ends with "Lost connection to device" while installing. I also tried it on a physical device, still won't work. I have tried numerous possible solution, but none of them worked.

```
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 5693): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
D/FlutterLocationService( 5693): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService( 5693): Binding to location service.
Lost connection to device.
Exited (1)
```

**What I've checked:**

- Memory enough
- No connection problem
- flutter doctor -v shows no issues
- Wipe Data of emulator and tried again

Some further information on what I'm using:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

**build.gradle/android:**

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
    
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
       
}
```

**build.gradle/app:**

```
defaultConfig {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.6.0' }
    }
    applicationId "com.praveeshramroop.athena"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    
}
```

Comment: what does your `flutter devices` say?

Comment: What do you mean by 'memory enough'? What memory are you referring to? Also, post the output of Flutter doctor -v